# Flyout causing the app to crash [Windows 10] C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I want the program to show the attached Flyout when user Holding the control (on the mobile) or when the user Right-click the control (on PC).

Here is my XAML :

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Cards" x:Key="card">
        <StackPanel x:Name="cardstack" Holding="cardstack_Holding" KeyDown="cardstack_KeyDown" >
            <StackPanel Background="Blue" Height="100" />
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout x:Name="optionpass">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="delete" Text="Delete" Click="delete_Click"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and this is my C# :

```
    private void cardstack_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }

    private void cardstack_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.RightButton)
        {
            FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
        }
    }
```

When I tap and Hold the Stackpanel on the mobile simulator, the Holding event works, but when I Right-click on my PC, it crashes! It says that "There are no attached Flyout!". I do not know what is wrong.

"Have you tried RightTapped event? Is it working?"

Yes and No :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out the solution to solve my problem.

Turns out you have to name the `MenuFlyout` like my one is `x:Name = "option_menu"`, and the `Flyoutbase.AttachedFlyout` cannot be in the `DataTemplate`, means you have to put it anywhere else except in the `DataTemplate`, so that the .cs file can find the name of the `MenuFlyout`.

Here is my C# :

```
public void cardstack_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        option_menu.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

private void cardstack_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Pointer pointr = e.Pointer;

        if (pointr.PointerDeviceType ==  Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
        {
            Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint pointrd = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as UIElement);
            if (pointrd.Properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
            {
                option_menu.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Notice that before this I use `ShowAttachedFlyout`, now I use `option_menu.ShowAt`.

`KeyDown` event somehow did not work with my app, so I used `PointerPressed` instead.

Hope this helps. (0w0)/